# marginal probability density function for variables with uneven range

Tags: probability, density-function

I'm working through some mock exam questions in preparation for an upcoming exam, and I'm stumped on this one.

given that $ f(x,y) = \frac 3 4 y, \quad x \in ]-1,1[, \quad 0 \le y \le x+1$, 
I'm to prove that the density functions are:

$f(x)=\frac 3 8 (1+x)^2$ if $x \in ]-1,1[$,

$f(y)=\frac 3 4 y(2-y)$ if $y \in ]0,2[$.

To find $x$, I integrated for $y$

$$f(x) = \int_0^{1+x} \frac 3 4 y\ dy = \frac 3 8 y^2 \Big| _0^{(1+x)} = \frac 3 8 (1+x)^2 .$$

So far so good, but when I try to integrate for $x$ I get lost.

$$f(y) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac 3 4 y\ dx = \frac  3 4 xy \Big| _{-1}^1 = - \frac  3 4 y + \frac  3 4 y=0 .$$

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $x$ does not run from $-1$ to $1$ in your second integral...from the condition $0\leq y\leq x+1$ we learn that $x\geq y-1$...so your integral should go from $y-1$ to $1$...and btw the result you quote for $f(y)$ does not smell right (it does not integrate to $1$).

Comment: so you're saying that $$ f(y) = \int_{y-1}^1 \frac 3 4 y\ dx \neq \frac 3 4 y\ (2-y) | y \in]0,2[ $$?

Comment: you wrote $f(y)=(3/4)(2-y)$ in your question - whose integral between 0 and 2 in $y$ gives $3/2$, not $1$

Comment: oh, my bad, forgot the extra y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues to consider:

- $\frac  3 4 xy \Big| _{-1}^1 = +\frac  3 4 y + \frac  3 4 y = \frac  3 2 y$, though ...
- ... for given $y$ from $0$ to $2$, you might have $y-1 \le x \lt 1$ as the limits of integration

Comment: wait, do you subtract the one from the other?

Comment: @Plissken If you are talking about my first point, consider a similar example:  $\displaystyle \int_{x=2}^{5} y \, dx =  xy \Big| _{x=2}^5 = 5y-2y=3y$.  If you are talking about my second point, then the value of $y$ constrains the possible values of $x$

Comment: I'm talking about the calculated limits i guess

$ \int_a^b x\ dx =x ]_a^b=b-a $?
I thought you added the two, but now that I think about it, the other way around makes more sense.

Comment: OK though $\displaystyle \int_{x=a}^b x\ dx =\tfrac{x^2}{2}\Big|_a^b=\tfrac{b^2}{2}-\tfrac{a^2}{2}$

Comment: yeah, I'm starting to not count on top marks for this exam, but am I then right that the calculation I'm looking for is:

$$f(y) = \int_{y-1}^1 \frac 3 4 y\ dx =  \frac 3 4 y  \int_{y-1}^1 x\ dx= \frac 3 4 y \big[ x \Big] _{y-1}^1 =  \frac 3 4 y( 1-(y-1))= \frac 3 4 y (2-y) .$$

Comment: I meant $\frac 3 4 y \int _{y-1}^1 1\ dx$

Comment: As a check, see $\displaystyle \int_{y=0}^2 \frac 3 4 y (2-y) \, dy = 1$, which is encouraging